# Load iframe after onload

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, onload

I have got a blog and I would like youtube and vimeo videos to load after the page is loaded, because as of now these videos block the loading of the rest of the content.

This is the code I generate for each post:

```
public function generateVimeoVideo($class){

    return "<iframe class='".$class."' src='//player.vimeo.com/video/".$this->vimeo_video_id."' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>";


}
```

How do I load this after onload ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically capture the values returned by `generateVimeoVideo($class)()` in a javascript variable and create the iframe element on the page you are displaying it only once your dom has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It's Very simple .

Please make the function on the click event.

```
function change_frame(){
document.getElementById("captchaDiv").src='http://www.domain.com/captcha.php?'+(new Date()).getMilliseconds();
return true;
}


<a href='#' onClick="change_frame();return false" />
```

Hope it Work !!!

Answer (score 0):

it should work like this HTML please check it and give me reply .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function loadFrame(){
document.getElementById('theframe').innerHTML='<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>';
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span id="theframe"><noscript><iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe></noscript></span><br>
The rest of your page here.
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
onload=loadFrame;
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 


?>
<html>
<body>
<script>
  function generateVimeoVideo($class,$vid){
    var putYouTubeHere= document.getElementById('putYouTubeHere');
    putYouTubeHere.innerHTML=  "<iframe class='" + $class + "' src='//player.vimeo.com/video/" + $vid + "' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>";


}
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){ generateVimeoVideo('classname','<?php  echo $this->vimeo_video_id;?>');}, false );
</script>
<div  id="putYouTubeHere"></div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery `bind`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>


      <style type='text/css'>
        body {background-color:#222;}

    #frameContainer {
      background:white url('http://hompimpa.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/images/loading.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;
      margin:30px;
    }

    #frameContainer iframe {
      display:block;
      padding:5%;
      border:none !important;
    }

      </style>



    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

    $(window).bind("load", function() {
       $('#frameContainer').html('<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/" + $vid + " frameborder="0" width="90%" height="220px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>'); 
    });

    //]]>  

    </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="frameContainer"></div>


</body>


</html>
```